# How to set element to layer between elements with sticky and fixed position

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, styled-components

I have such code example:

```
 <div style="width: 500px; height: 520px; position: sticky; z-index: 10;">
    <div style="position: fixed; width: 100px; height: 100px; z-index: 50;"></div>
 </div>
```

also I have a Shadow DOM, with `element A`, which I want to set between child and parent div

when I set z-index: 11 to this `element A` (between z-index of parent and child) the `element A` is above parent and child div
when I set it z-index: 9, the `element A` is under parent and child div

How I can set `element A` between child and parent div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have an element outside the parent be between the parent and child. That's because the `sticky` position (like most positions) creates a new stacking context:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context

In other words, anything below a z-index of 50 will be below *both* elements, anything above 50 will be above *both* elements.

To achieve what you're trying to do, the other elements must both be in a stacking context that is shared by `element A`. Assuming the parent must remain `sticky`, you can either move the child outside the parent, or put the new div inside the parent.

`element A` is red, the `sticky` div is blue, and the child is green.

```html
<p>Scroll Down</p>
 

 <div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; position: sticky; z-index: 10; background: blue; top:50px; margin-top: 300px"></div>
 <!-- Child moved to main stacking context -->
 <div style="position: sticky; width: 100px; height: 100px; z-index: 50; background: green; top:50px; margin-top: 200px"></div>
 
   <!-- New div with z-index between -->
 <div style="position: fixed; width: 150px; height: 150px; z-index: 11; background: red; top:50px;"></div>
 
 <!-- Make some scrolling room -->
 <div style="height:2000px; width:1px;"></div>
```

OR

```html
<p>Scroll Down</p>
 
 <div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; position: sticky; z-index: 10; background: blue; top:50px; margin-top: 300px">
    <!-- New div with z-index between -->
    <div style="position: fixed; width: 150px; height: 150px; z-index: 11; background: red; top:50px;"></div>
    <div style="position: sticky; width: 100px; height: 100px; z-index: 50; background: green; top:50px; margin-top: 200px"></div>
 </div>

 <!-- Make some scrolling room -->
 <div style="height:2000px; width:1px;"></div>
```

You could put the child inside the new div as well.

Answer (score 0):

The parent element should be `position: relative`.

Then the `child element` applies on `inside the parent`.

Note that child element should have `top, bottom, left, right`.

```
.parent {
   position: relative;
   width: 500px;
   height: 500px;
}

.child {
   width: 350px;
   height: 350px;
   background-color: red;
   position: fixed;
   bottom: 0;
   right: 0;
}
```